# autohotkeys Map Caps + ijkl to arrow keys when doing alt+tab

Tags: autohotkey

I have an autohotkeys script to map CapsLock + i j k l to be my arrow keys:

```
CapsLock & h::
   Send, {Left down}{Left up}
Return

CapsLock & k::
   Send, {Down down}{Down up}
Return

CapsLock & i::
   Send, {Up down}{Up up}
Return

CapsLock & l::
   Send, {Right down}{Right up}
Return
```

And it works some of the time. However when I use Caps + i j k l with another key like shift for highlighting, or alt + tab, it ceases to work properly.

How do I add these use cases to my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap) and you're all good.

```
CapsLock & h::Left
CapsLock & k::Down
CapsLock & i::Up
CapsLock & l::Right
```

There was no use to send both the down and up events anyway.
And the specific thing in the remapping syntax which makes this work, is that it uses the [blind send mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind). You can read up on it if you're interested, but basically it avoids releasing modifier keys which might be held down when input is to be sent.

Comment: Interesting I didn't realize that. Thanks bro.